# When is age discrimination actually illegal?

Tags: england-and-wales, discrimination, equality-act-2010

Any information page on the protections of the Equality Act 2010 will list age among the protected characteristics, which it clearly is.

But a host of provisions seem to make exceptions to this characteristic, such as to largely defang and neuter it.

From section 28(1)(a), to [this](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2012/2466/article/4/made), age discrimination in many scenarios seems to be rendered lawful. What are these scenarios, and what do they not cover?

Is it an accurate understanding of section 28(1)(a) to say that it means that individuals under the age of 18 cannot rely on the protected characteristic of age, but that it otherwise changes nothing about the anti discrimination law?

Note: I am fully aware of the related question linked in the comments about children’s menus. Please see my comment on how this question relates to and differs from that one.